# Firebug 2.0 with FF 30 can't set breakpoints

Tags: firefox, firebug

When I set a breakpoint with Firebug 2.0 in Firefox 30, I can't seem to set breakpoints using the line numbers column. It just throws up a spinner instead of the red circle.

Is there some new configuration option or something else that I am missing? Do I have to execute my code for the breakpoint to take effect?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a bug in Firebug 2.0, which you should report in the [Firebug issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry), so the team behind Firebug can fix it.

Before you do this you should follow the steps described on the [first aid page for Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firstaid) to track the issue further down. These steps are (copied from the first aid page):

1. Open the [Firefox Error Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Error_Console) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). Any errors related to Firebug? Copy them and remember to include them in your report.
2. [Create a new profile](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Firebug_into_a_clean_profile), install Firebug, reproduce the problem. Still a bug? Report the problem, else
3. Return to your previous profile, open the Add-ons Manager via *Firefox menu bar > Tools > Add-ons*, *Firefox menu button > Add-ons* or `about:addons` to disable all extensions except Firebug. Solved? Enable the other extensions again one by one until you find the buggy one and report it, else
4. Open the *Troubleshooting Information* via *Firefox menu button > ? > Troubleshooting Information*, click *Open Containing Folder*, open `prefs.js` in a text editor, copy all lines containing `extensions.firebug` into a separate text file, reset all options (via the Firebug icon menu in the upper left corner of Firebug) *> Options > Reset All Firebug Options*, reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching the created file, else
5. In the profile folder go to *firebug/*, move the file *breakpoints.json* (if it doesn't exist, go to step 4) out of that folder, reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching your *breakpoints.json* (**Attention:** *breakpoints.json* contains the URLs of all breakpoints you set, so make sure there's nothing that shouldn't be public), else
6. In the profile folder under *firebug/* move the file *annotations.json* (if it doesn't exist, go to step 5) out of that folder, reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching your *annotations.json* (**Attention:** *annotations.json* contains the URLs of all pages you enabled Firebug for, so make sure there's nothing that shouldn't be public)