# The breakpoint in Firebug is a grey spinning circle

Tags: firebug

A breakpoint in Firebug was supposed to look like a red dot. However, in my firebug, it is always a grey spinning circle. My program cannot be step into a spinning circle beakpoint.

I tried to reinstall firebug and firefox, but the issue still exists. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a Firebug bug. If you have a reproducible test case, please [open an issue](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry) so we can try to fix it!

Comment: It is similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185721/firebug-2-0-with-ff-3-0-cant-set-breakpoints, and the answer can resolve it.